# use of mail on command line

Tags: mail

I am trying to use the mail on the command line  to send a message to don
How do you end the message
I do 
mail don

put my message in and cannot send it. I have to kill the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press CTRL-D.

Example:

```
$ mail -s "Hello World" someone@example.com
Cc: 
Hi Peter
How are you
I am fine
Good Bye
<Ctrl+D>
```

http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples/